# Why does logging with pytest parametrize return lines in logging, increment for every parameter?

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I wrote a Python code where I am learning how to use pytest and logging for a test I am doing. I want to send in a list of parameters which a pytest test_ function will loop through. This is my code:

```
import pytest
import numpy as np
import logging

class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture
    def initializeLogger(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(r'C:\Users\user\Data\Cross correlation\RunLog.log')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        return logger

    # Define parameters
    params = []
    params.append({'no' : 1})
    params.append({'no' : 2})
    params.append({'no' : 3})



    @pytest.mark.parametrize("params", params)
    def test_ZeroI(self, initializeLogger, params):
        logger = initializeLogger
        read = params['no']
        logger.info(f'Value inputted: {read}, Value read: {read}')
        print('success')
        assert params['no'] == read
```

I have defined initializeLogger(self) as a pytest fixture which is initialized before my main test function: test_ZeroI(..) is called.

The initializeLogger(self) function simply initializes the logger, and I attach it to a file_handler which creates the file for me. Then I return the logger.

I create a list called params, and I add dictionary values with the key 'no' along with the values which I want to iterate through; so in this scenario: 1, 2, 3.

the testZeroI() function then (from my understanding) should run three times, with the parameters 1, 2 and 3 respectively in order. I added the line: logger.info(f'Value inputted: {read}, Value read: {read}') which simply just reads the value and outputs into the log.

However, the problem is in the log, this is what I see:

INFO:module2:Value inputted: 1, Value read: 1
INFO:module2:Value inputted: 2, Value read: 2
INFO:module2:Value inputted: 2, Value read: 2
INFO:module2:Value inputted: 3, Value read: 3
INFO:module2:Value inputted: 3, Value read: 3
INFO:module2:Value inputted: 3, Value read: 3

As you can see, value 1 is logged once. Value 2 is logged twice. Value 3 is logged three times. What am I doing wrong in my code? My purpose is so that my code outputs a log like this:

INFO:module2:Value inputted: 1, Value read: 1
INFO:module2:Value inputted: 2, Value read: 2
INFO:module2:Value inputted: 3, Value read: 3

Comment: In your fixture `initializeLogger` you call `logger.addHandler(file_handler)` each time on the same logger, so you get an additional logger each time you use the fixture. You have to call the code only once, for example by checking if it is iniatialized, or in a class setup method.

Comment: Do you know if there are any markers I can use it so the fixture function initializeLogger is only called once for the whole test?

Comment: I added an answer with different possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

In your fixture `initializeLogger` you call `logger.addHandler(file_handler)` each time on the same logger, so you get an additional logger each time you use the fixture.

You can either make sure that the code is only called once (for example using a singleton, or put it in class setup), or remove the logger after usage.
If using a fixture, you could do:

```python
@pytest.fixture
def get_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    ...
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    yield logger
    logger.handlers.clear()
```

or you can use `setup`/`teardown` to do the same:

```python
class TestClass:

   def setup_method(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        ...
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

   def teardown_method(self):
       self.logger.handlers.clear()
```

If you want to use the same handler throughout the tests, you can use a class initializer:

```python
class TestClass:
   logger = None

   @classmethod
   def setup_class(cls):
       cls.logger = initializeLogger()

   @classmethod
   def teardown_class(cls):
       cls.logger.handlers.clear()
```